# Why i get 'no such file or directory' with find

Tags: shell, find

I use `find` to list all the files under some `postfix` directory.

Here is the command:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/{incoming,maildrop,active,hold,deferred}/ -type f|wc -l
```

I run this in a crontab and something error is mailed to me:

```
find: `/var/spool/postfix/incoming/D9AE7E3F48': No such file or directory
find: `/var/spool/postfix/active/EE244E0327': No such file or directory
find: `/var/spool/postfix/active/EE57FE0C63': No such file or directory
find: `/var/spool/postfix/active/EDC55E0C53': No such file or directory
```

So, i am curious about the error. Can someone explain it to me.

Comment: the directories are disappearing as mails are processed. `find` sees them from the parent dir, but by the time it looks in detail they are gone. or your cron user has no permissions.

Comment: @meuh, can i just ignore this error without affecting other error which may be come up in any time.

Comment: you could temporarily stop postfix from running whilst you do your check. but I'm sure there's a postfix command to list these queue entries for you which you could use instead.

Comment: @meuh,  that's right. I have checked what `find` will do with `strace`. It is showed that `find` will call `getdents` to get all the dentries first and then use that info to do some more job with 'newfsstatat'.